# Radio buttons change size instead of cutting off and showing overflow-x scroll bar

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm attempting to only allow 5 radio buttons to view instead of all, and if you want to see more you should be able to scroll to the right.

Image 1 css code has width: 300px;

[image]

Image 2 css code has width: 160px; (cutting it at 5 items)

[image]

As you can see when I make the width smaller the element height changes and the other buttons go down. What I attempt to do is cut at the five element and have an horizontal scroll bar. I played a lot with css properties but couldn't get it.

```
(my current code in angular)

<div class="page_selector">
    <span class="ps_item" *ngFor="let page of page_selector_items">
        <input type="radio" id="{{page.number}}" name="page_number" (click)="changePage(page.number)">
        <label for="{{page.number}}">{{page.number}}</label>
    </span>
</div>

(code in normal html)

<div class="page_selector">
    <span class="ps_item">
        <input type="radio" id="1" name="page_number">
        <label for="1">1</label>
    </span>
    <span class="ps_item">
        <input type="radio" id="2" name="page_number">
        <label for="2">2</label>
    </span>
    <span class="ps_item">
        <input type="radio" id="3" name="page_number">
        <label for="3">3</label>
    </span>
    [...same 5 more times]
</div>
```

```
(my current code in scss)

.page_selector {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    overflow: visible hidden;
    margin-left: 60%;
    width: 160px;

    .ps_item {
        margin-left: 15px;
        display: inline-block;
        
        label {
            display: block;
        }
    }
}

(code in normal css)

.page_selector {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    overflow: visible hidden;
    margin-left: 60%;
    width: 160px;
}
.ps_item {
    margin-left: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.ps_item label {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: set overflow:auto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `overflow: auto` with a fixed width. The child elements (span)  needs a fixed with of 20%:

```css
.page_selector {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.ps_item {
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="page_selector">
  <span class="ps_item">
    <input type="radio" id="1" name="page_number">
    <label for="1">1</label>
  </span>
  <span class="ps_item">
    <input type="radio" id="2" name="page_number">
    <label for="2">2</label>
  </span>
  <span class="ps_item">
    <input type="radio" id="3" name="page_number">
    <label for="3">3</label>
  </span>
  <span class="ps_item">
    <input type="radio" id="4" name="page_number">
    <label for="4">4</label>
  </span>
  <span class="ps_item">
    <input type="radio" id="5" name="page_number">
    <label for="5">5</label>
  </span>
  <span class="ps_item">
    <input type="radio" id="6" name="page_number">
    <label for="6">6</label>
  </span>
  <span class="ps_item">
    <input type="radio" id="7" name="page_number">
    <label for="7">7</label>
  </span>
  <span class="ps_item">
    <input type="radio" id="8" name="page_number">
    <label for="8">8</label>
  </span>
  <span class="ps_item">
    <input type="radio" id="9" name="page_number">
    <label for="9">9</label>
  </span>
</div>
```